# Best way to display Content and then return to calling Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, android-contentprovider, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I want to grab the Name and PhoneNumber vals from the Contacts Content Provider and display them to the user so that s/he can select 1..N of those Contacts. I would like this "Activity" to pop up out of the Activity which invokes it.

Is an AlertDialog the best way to tackle this? Alternatively, I could make it a separate 
Activity that returns to the Activity that invoked it once the user has finished making 
the selections...

Comment: Hey Clay, generally questions that ask "Is this the best way to do this?" generate debate and are usually closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the methods you've proposed would work. Which is best depends on many other things about your application.